# jquery auto complete not receives data

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

```
                    var projects2 = <?php include_once "AutoCompleteHandler.php"; ?>;
    var projects23= <?php include_once "AutoCompleteHandler.php"; ?>;
    $("#p_name").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: projects2,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#p_name").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {


            return false;
        }
    })
            .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
                .append("<a>" + item.label + "/" + item.p_gender + "/" + item.p_age + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
    };

    $("#p_tp").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: projects23,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#p_tp").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {


            return false;
        }
    })
            .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
                .append("<a>" + item.label + "/" + item.p_gender + "/" + item.p_age + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
    };



}
```

i used above code segment to populate my two text fields with data(Auto Complete).but when i try this o get following error.project2 and project 23 recieves json data from php file called **AutoCompleteHandler.php**

```
      Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

This is my json output

```
        [
           {
           label: "kasun" , 

          p_nic: "880020110v", 

          p_age: "02-01-1988" ,

          p_gender: "Male" 

          } 
         ]
```

Comment: Its just a wild guess that you might be getting this error because of either or both of these lines : `var projects2 = <?php include_once "AutoCompleteHandler.php"; ?>;
    var projects23= <?php include_once "AutoCompleteHandler.php"; ?>;` You could view the source code of the generated HTML to verify it.

Comment: but this method works for  one text field.